# addClass and removeClass not getting called properly

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form with text fields and drodowns. I am trying to validate the dropdowns on the change of the dropdown and submit of the form.

```
var flag = false;
$('#submit_form .required').change(function (e) {
    var input = $(this);
    input.next('ul.error_text').remove();
    input.removeClass('highlight');
    if (!input.val()) {
        input.removeClass('green');
        input.addClass('highlight');
        var $msg = input.attr('title');
        input.after('<ul class="error_text"><li>' + $msg + '</li></ul>');
        flag = true;
    } else {
        if (flag == true) {
            input.addClass('green');
        } else {
            input.next('ul.error_text').remove();
            input.removeClass('highlight');
            input.removeClass('green');
        }
    }
});
var flag1 = true;
$('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    input.next('ul.error_text').remove();
    input.removeClass('highlight');
    if (!input.val()) {
        input.removeClass('green');
        input.addClass('highlight');
        var $msg = input.attr('title');
        input.after('<ul class="error_text"><li>' + $msg + '</li></ul>');
        flag = true;
        flag1 = false;
    }
});
return flag1;
```

On submit of the form, if no values are selected in dropdown it should show red and show required text. On select of the value, the dropdown should become green. Now if no values are selected, red highlight is coming but the Required text below that is not coming. Also if I select a value, red highlight is not becoming green. I tink I am missing something here..Could somebody help me figure it out?

Comment: can you create a fiddle for better understanding!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/4/

Comment: Why do you have there twice `select` with ID `choice`??

Comment: the second select is hidden..just to make sure that the logic applies only to the visible select elements

Answer (score 0):

This is outside any function (last line) and it should be in the function:

```
return flag1;
```

Here it is modified:

```
var flag = false;
$('#submit_form .required').change(function (e) {
    var input = $(this);
    input.next('ul.error_text').remove();
    input.removeClass('highlight');
    if (!input.val()) {
        input.removeClass('green');
        input.addClass('highlight');
        var $msg = input.attr('title');
        input.after('<ul class="error_text"><li>' + $msg + '</li></ul>');
        flag = true;
    } else {
        if (flag == true) {
            input.addClass('green');
        } else {
            input.next('ul.error_text').remove();
            input.removeClass('highlight');
            input.removeClass('green');
        }
    }
});
var flag1 = true;
$('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    input.next('ul.error_text').remove();
    input.removeClass('highlight');
    if (!input.val()) {
        input.removeClass('green');
        input.addClass('highlight');
        var $msg = input.attr('title');
        input.after('<ul class="error_text"><li>' + $msg + '</li></ul>');
        flag = true;
        flag1 = false;
    }
    return flag1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to place `return flag1;` in the submit function instead:

```
$('#submit_form').submit(function () {
    var flag1 = true;
    $('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
       var input = $(this);
       input.next('ul.error_text').remove();
       input.removeClass('highlight');
       if (!input.val()) {
          input.removeClass('green');
          input.addClass('highlight');
          var $msg = input.attr('title');
          input.after('<ul class="error_text"><li>' + $msg + '</li></ul>');
          flag = true;
          flag1 = false;
       }
   });
   return flag1; //<----------place here...
});  //<----------------- end of submit
```

[**Fiddle to try**](http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/5/)